# How can I shorten a C code that repeatedly outputs a number?

Tags: code-golf, tips

I wrote a code that separates the numbers from 1 to 9999 by comma

```c
void p(n){printf("%d,",n);if(n<9999){p(n+1);}}main(){p(1);}
```

Is there a way to make this short code without using a repeat statement?

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf! Just a word of caution: we'll do anything we can on this site to  save a single byte, which usually leads to terrible code that should not be actually used for anything serious.

Answer (score 16):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 40 bytes by Sisyphus, exit by stack overflow

```c
i;main(){main(dprintf(i++<9999,"%d,"));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z/TOjcxM09DsxpMpRQUZeaVpGlkamvbWAKBjpJqio6SpqZ17f//AA)

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 41 bytes by dingledooper

```c
i;main(){++i<1e4&&main(printf("%d,",i));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z/TOjcxM09Ds1pbO9PGMNVETQ3MLyjKzCtJ01BSTdFR0snU1LSu/f8fAA)

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 42 bytes, original

```c
main(i){i<1e4&&main(i+1,printf("%d,",i));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z83MTNPI1OzOtPGMNVETQ3C1TbUKSjKzCtJ01BSTdFR0snU1LSu/f8fAA)

`main` can be used to recurse

Comment: 41: `n;main(){++n<1e4&&main(printf("%d,",n));}`

Comment: 39; `main(i){for(;i<1e4;)printf("%d,",i++);}`

Comment: @HudsonGraeme I follow rule `without using a repeat statement?`

Comment: 40: `i;main(){main(dprintf(i++<9999,"%d,"));}`

Comment: The `dprintf` solution has the distinct disadvantage that it doesn't end normally, but instead ends with a segmentation fault from trying to write to filedescriptor 0.

Comment: @A.R. [It's not a fault from writing to stdin](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z/TOjcxM09DszqloCgzryRNw0BHSTVFR0kTIg4TzdTWtrEEAqikpnXt//8A)

Comment: "exit by stack overflow" That phrase just embodies everything I love about this site so well.

Answer (score 14):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/) (Linux only), 31 bytes

```c
main(){system("seq -s, 9999");}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z83MTNPQ7O6uLK4JDVXQ6k4tVBBt1hHwRIIlDSta///BwA)

Comment: 31; `main(){system("seq -s, 9999");}`

Comment: That's what I started with, then for some reason, I thought it needed a space after the commas.

Comment: Hm, surprised `seq` is not POSIX

Comment: @pipe BSDs ship [jot](https://man.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?jot(1)) instead, neither is standardized by POSIX

Comment: OpenBSD and supposedly NetBSD have a seq command also, and it supports the s option.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 30 bytes by Karl Knechtel

```python
print(*range(1,10000),sep=',')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v6AoM69EQ6soMS89VcNQx9AACDR1ilMLbNV11DX//wcA)

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 36 bytes by onetoinfinity

```python
print(str(list(range(10000)))[4:-1])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v6AoM69Eo7ikSCMns7hEoygxLz1Vw9AACDQ1NaNNrHQNYzX//wcA)

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 39 bytes by UndoneStudios

```python
i=0
while i<1e5:print(end='%d,'%i);i+=1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P9PWgKs8IzMnVSHTxjDV1KqgKDOvRCM1L8VWXTVFR101U9M6U9vW8P9/AA)

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 40 bytes by Lemon

```python
print(",".join(map(str,range(1,10000))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v6AoM69EQ0lHSS8rPzNPIzexQKO4pEinKDEvPVXDUMfQAAg0geD/fwA)

Comment: Feel free to make any suggestions :)

Comment: range end is exclusive so you need 10000 or it will only print up to 9998

Comment: Whops, I forgot about that one. Thanks :)

Comment: -1 byte: https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P9PWgKs8IzMnVSHTxjDV1KqgKDOvRCM1L8VWXTVFR101U9M6U9vW8P9/AA

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf!

Comment: 36: `print(str(list(range(10000)))[4:-1])`

Comment: 30: `print(*range(1,10000),sep=',')`

Answer (score 1):

## C# 71 bytes

<s>`Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",",Enumerable.Range(1, 999).ToList()));`</s>

Saved 14 bytes thanks to Jupotters comment

```
Console.Write(string.Join(",",Enumerable.Range(1,9999)));
```

Comment: 57: `Console.Write(string.Join(",",Enumerable.Range(1,9999)));`

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 15 bytes

```powershell
1..9999-join","
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/31BPzxIIdLPyM/OUdJT@/wcA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>36</s> 35 bytes

```hs
main=putStr.init.tail$show[1..9999]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/PzcxM8@2oLQkuKRILzMvs0SvJDEzR6U4I7882lBPzxIIYv//BwA)

### Old version

```hs
main=putStr.init.tail.show$[1..9999]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/PzcxM8@2oLQkuKRILzMvs0SvJDEzR684I79cJdpQT88SCGL//wcA)

Answer (score -2):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 27 bytes

```
Range@9999~StringRiffle~","
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78H6xg@z8oMS891cESCOqCS4oy89KDMtPSclLrlHSU/gcA@SXRwbH/AQ)

`Range@9999` (10 bytes) almost does it...